# When Running Jmeter test from java its not using the properties

Tags: java, maven, jmeter, beanshell

I have a test in JMeter, and with GUI it runs perfectly, but when I run it using my Java code (like from here:
http://blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui), I can't retrieve the params from the properties.
If I print them in the beanshell log, I can see them.
But, when I'm trying to use this params in thread Group as number of users it is not working.

More info:

1. I have a setUp thread that counts the rows of the csv file and
   inserting a value to a property so that in the next thread I will
   use this property to set the amount of users. (this logic is
   happening twice during the test).
2. I'm using Maven dependencies of: *ApacheJMeter_http V2.11* (2.13 creates a conflict with common-pools2 and d-haven)
3. eclipse (if it matters)
4. The goal is that the only parameter I will pass to the test run is the test file.
5. The prop statement in the test looks like this `${__P(paramName)}` also tried `$(__property{paramName})`.
6. I have also created a property in the file itself instead of using in beanshell `JMeterUtils.setProperty("paramName","5");`

Adding the bean shell snippet:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
import java.io.*;

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\res\\movieResultData.csv"));
String line;

int counter = 0;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
   counter++;
}
br.close();
JMeterUtils.setProperty("statsThreadNum",Integer.toString(counter-1));
```

My java Code:

```
    @Test
public void ttt() throws Exception {
    // JMeter Engine
    StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();

    // Initialize Properties, logging, locale, etc.
    JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("C:\\apache-jmeter-2.12\\bin\\jmeter.properties");
    JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome("C:\\apache-jmeter-2.12");
    //JMeterUtils.initLogging();// you can comment this line out to see extra log messages of i.e. DEBUG level
    JMeterUtils.initLocale();

    // Initialize JMeter SaveService
    SaveService.loadProperties();

    // Load existing .jmx Test Plan
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("C:\\apache-jmeter-2.12\\bin\\statsTests2.jmx");
    HashTree testPlanTree = SaveService.loadTree(in);
    in.close();

    // Run JMeter Test
    jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
    jmeter.run();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax should be:

```
${__P(prop_name)}
```

If you are running it through a java only implementation, be sure you pass the property file to your JVM as it starts up or use the following code snippit:

```
  JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("/path/to/your/jmeter/bin/jmeter.properties");
```

Are you using Apache Exec to start JMeter from java as an external process?
If so, be sure you build your CMD line statement using the following options:

```
-p, --propfile {argument}
            the jmeter property file to use
-G, --globalproperty (argument)[=(value)]
            Define Global properties (sent to servers)
```

It might be useful to show us a snippit of your Beanshell that you use to set the properties in SetUp.

Edit:
I believe the issue may be with how your Beanshell is accessing properties.  I've never had to access the JMeterUtils class to manipulate variables or properties within a JMX.

Beanshell Syntax for assigning a property:

```
props.put("test_prop_name","prop_value");
```

Beanshell syntax for getting a property:

```
props.get("test_prop_name");
```

Beanshell syntax for assigning a property to a variable:

```
vars.put("test_var_name",props.get("test_prop"));
```

This variable can then be referenced in a sampler like this:

```
${test_var_name}
```

Or you should be able to accesss the property directly in a sampler like this:

```
${__P(test_prop_name)}
```

Also, use the following POM if you wish to fix the Maven issues with JMeter 2.13:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_config</artifactId>
        <version>2.13</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-math3</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-pool2</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_java</artifactId>
        <version>2.13</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-math3</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
            </exclusion>

            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-pool2</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. Well, the pom is fixed thanks for that :). but the problem still stands. I did use the $ sign its was a typo. also edited and provided the beanshell code i use.

Comment: Hey sorry it took me a bit to see this comment!  Editing my response so I can use the code format.  Check for it above the POM section.

Comment: However, I should warn you:  JMeter may initialize all thread groups at the very start of the test, even if its set to run them consecutively.  It might not be possible to have setUp populate a property to be used as "number of threads" for a 2nd group.  I will try to investigate.

Comment: It works.  Be sure the test plan has "run thread groups consecutively" checked off.

Comment: OK. so i changed it to props put. But still not working. When i run from CMD its fine But my java code i use to run is jmeter api. thats the only diffrence. adding my code.